# How to do vlookup in HiveSQL?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, vlookup

I'm new to Hive and still learning about it, but have a small problem here. Really need help on this thing..

So, I have a table of students' grade as below:

[image: Grade Table]

*exam_index shows how many exams each student have taken, 1 means first exam, 2 means second exam.

and I'd like to convert it into this expected result:

[image: Result Table]

Any idea of doing this? Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select student,
       max(case when exam_index = 1 then grade end) as grade_1,
       max(case when exam_index = 2 then grade end) as grade_2
from t
group by student;
```

Comment: Hi Linoff! Thanks for your answer and your correction, really appreciate it! I got your answer, but then if I expand the table as above (I've edited it), then would I need to use "with... as..." ? Or could I just expand your given query (no need to use with...as...)? Need further explanation on this, thanks very much!